# best way to secure sessions (consulting)

Tags: php, security, session, session-cookies

Ok, yes, I've read the other Qs regarding this topic, but I have several questions more and some Qs were several years old.

Anyways, I'm building an admin cp for an insurance company that contains sensitive client info. Such as passwords, social security numbers, and drivers #.

First Q:
What's more secure, php sessions or cookies? From my understanding of cookies, you can strict them to http only and SSL. Don't know if you can do the same with php sessions. Seems also that php sessions are just quick cookies. Cookies seem more flexible and just as reliable. FYI, I'm using Cookies with http and SSL only. Is there a good reason to use php sessions in MY case?

Second Q:
My sessions/login work like this:
* Passwords are salted and hashed
* Sessions are 32 random chars long
* Sessions are validated when user enters correct pw and are tied to the user's IP
* When a user logs in, the session id and user's password are stored in 2 separate cookies

If the sessions are validated via user pw and tied to the user's IP, can I just have the session Cookie and remove the pw cookie? since I think it's kinda redundant since you can only get a session id if you enter the correct PW. I rather have the session id expose in a cookie than the pw (though it's still salted and hashed).

Appreciate it if my two Qs can be answered. Additional security advice is welcomed :D

Note: Sessions are tied to IP because it increases security greatly. I rather have my users a bit inconvenienced in having to enter their pw when their IP changes when we have SSNs and Driver License #s in our db. Only 3-5 users will have access to the system too.

Comment: why you need to store password in cookie.session_id on https should be enough..you can have timeout for sessions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do **not** ever store the user's password in a cookie, in no form of representation.
- Regenerate the session ID often
- Use strong hashes (no MD5) like SHA512 (consider also [stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) the hash)
- Sensitive data should be on the server-sided session store:

  - Cookies are sent along every request to the cookies domain, hence increasing the chances of being intercepted greatly. Server sided session data is only outputted when needed.
- Pass along a session-tied identifier to each sensitive request as an auth token to avoid [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF)
- Do not directly bind the session to an IP. Two people using the same AP or private ISP have the same IP and sessions could be mixed up.
- SSL is [not magical](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/beast_exploits_paypal_ssl/). Don't relay on it too much.

Comment: So cookie data is sent even if the script doesn't request it?

Comment: I don't see how sessions could be mixed up if under the same network. You would need to have the same ip AND session id(which is a random 32 char long). Reading your answer, I think I will switch to php sessions.

Comment: Yes. If the script is located inside the cookie domain. This also applies to images and other static content.

Comment: *Do not **directly** bind [...] to an IP*.

Comment: What do you mean directly? Right now I'm going to use php sessions and set it equal to a random 32 characters and bind it to the user's IP. So the user needs to have the correct session ID and IP. I think I will also store the user's userid in a cookie.

Comment: No session identifier, just to the IP. That's what I understood from your question.

Comment: I'm going to tie the php session id(which is 32 characters) and the IP to the user's account. If I'm using php sessions I can't have a "remember me" tick box, correct? Since I think php sessions only last while the browser is opened.

Comment: The session id should only be tied to the session and regenerated often. It has to be volatile, mutable, hard to spoof. I would not recommend a "remember me" function in such a sensitive environment.

Comment: By regenerate do you mean create a new php session when user is logged in and is browsing the admin cp? So I would have reinitialize the php session and update the database with the new session id? Would this cause a load on the server? Since I would have to authenticate the session then right afterwards change the session id. Or do you recommend to change the session id, say, every 24 hours? or every time the user loads a new page?

Thanks for the help! you really provided me with some good insight.

Comment: I'd say you regenerate it every 3 minutes or 5 requests whatever comes first. http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Sessions are stored on server, cookies are stored on the client (browser). Session data that belongs to a user is identified by a cookie (Session ID).

I'd say Sessions are safer (you can also apply some encryption for better security).

1. Don't store the users password in a cookie. Not a good practice even if it's hashed.
   You can store an encrypted serialized array containing necessary info to authenticate the user : ip, user agent, username, user id, but not the password.

You can also make the site (admin CP) work on SSL only. That way data is not visible in plain text on network.

Comment: Would storing the session id in the cookie and pulling it when when the user refreshes/revisits. My sessions are stored in the database, so when the user has a session id in their cookie I grab it and check if it exists in the database. If the session id that the user provided via cookie exists, then verify the IP. That's how my sessions work thus far.

The only way to hack the admin cp is to steal the session id and be under the same network/ip. I also made it that the sessions expire within 24 hours and rogue sessions that are older than 7 days are deleted.

Comment: I was reading that the user agent is not a good idea to use as authentication because it could be spoof. Also, some browsers change their useragent from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the password in cookie salted and hashed? Beware - there is no good answer to this question!

Tying sessions to IPs really doesn't help much - IPs are cheap, easily spoofed etc. I'd go with SSL, cookies/sessions, perhaps even one-time-cookies, consumed and reset on each pageview.

Comment: Yes, the pw cookie is salted and hashed.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored on a server, either in a database, filesystem, memcache, etc. User is tied to the session by session id, which is stored at client either in a cookie or in a URL. Neither is "very very" secure, since session hijacking is possible by stealing session id. But since you've tied session id to an IP, you've done quite enough.

Now to password stored in a cookie. Do not do this. **Never**. Even though they're hashes&salted, it's still better that attackers do not see them. You've got another level of security if they're only stored in a database, since in that case, attacker also has to break into db.

It helps if you're regenerating session id using `session_regenerate_id()` before doing any important action that could compromise the system. Also, take a look at XSS and CSRF attacks and mechanisms to prevent them, like form tokens.